# Magento Observer to check before logout

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, customer

I need to pass customer information to WordPress before s/he logout from Magento Automatically before session expired.

Which Observer event I need to use to resolved this issue?

Answer (score 1):

There is the event `customer_logout`. It is dispatched in `Mage_Customer_Model_Session::logout()` that is called in `Mage_Customer_AccountController::logoutAction()`.
You receive as parameter for the observer the customer instance.

You can build the observer like this:

```
public function customerLogout($observer) 
{
    $customer = $observer->getEvent()->getCustomer();
    $customerEmail = $customer->getEmail(); //or any other property
    //do something with $customer or $customerEmail or anything else
}
```

[EDIT after the question was edited]
I don't think there is an event thatis fired when the session is expired.
A session can expire for different reasons that don't necessarily depend on the system, like deleting the session cookie or the session file from `var/sessions`. You cannot track those.